# CMake command line arguments persistent

Tags: cmake, conditional-statements

I wrote a simple CMake script to test the use of command line arguments:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sample)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 99)

if(DEPLOY)
    message("deploying application")
endif()

if(DEV)
    message("developing application")
endif()
set(DEV OFF)
set(DEPLOY OFF)
message("lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen")
```

When I run `cmake CMakeLists.txt -DDEV=ON` , the result is:

```
developing application
lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

So far, so good. Now, I run `cmake CMakeLsists.txt -DDEPLOY=ON` and the result is:

```
deploying application
developing application
lorem ipsum dolor sit atmen
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
```

I was hoping to have only the line `deploying application`, instead, both conditional messages appeared. So it seems the `DEV` flag set previously is still on. How can I disble the persistent state of those flags?

Comment: "How can I disable the persistent state of those flags?" - By removing the build directory or just `CMakeCache.txt` file in it. Alternatively, you may unset selected variables with `-U` option (instead of `-D`).

Comment: @Tsyvarev I wanted an automatic way of unsetting the falg. I even tried `set(DEV OFF)` after the if statement, still did not work!

Comment: Note, that **unconditional** unsetting the variable may have **strange effects**. E.g., you may run `cmake -DDEV=ON` for configure the project in "developer mode" and later build the generated project with `make`. But when `make` is run, it checks whether some changing in the configuration has been done. If changes are detected, then reconfiguration process (similar to `cmake` invocation) will be performed **automatically**. But that time `-DDEV=ON` option won't be passed! So that automatic reconfiguration won't use "developer mode".

Comment: I would suggest you to use  [option](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/command/option.html) command for declare user-supplied project's options. For declare dependent options you may use [CMakeDependentOption](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.7/module/CMakeDependentOption.html) module. By using these standard tools you may avoid many surprises in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Had help from a friend!
From the documentation of `cmake unset()` command, I just had to replace the lines

```
set(DEV OFF)
set(DEPLOY OFF)
```

by these:

```
unset(DEV CACHE)
unset(DEPLOY CACHE)
```

[cmake `unset()` documentation](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/unset.html)